# Moving From Eclipse to Visual Studio 2008

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2008

After working in Eclipse for the past 3 years and memorizing all of the great shortcut keys and features, my new job has me moving back to Visual Studio.  I've found some listings of shortcut keys on VS, but am looking for a comprehensive guide mapping Eclipse features to Visual Studio.  Does anyone know of a good tutorial aimed at helping Eclipse users transition to VS?

Comment: Im working with both right know, my biggest problems are the shortcuts to go to references (vs=f12, eclipse=ctrl+click|f3) and the delete line shortcut.... :(...

Comment: We're in 2021 now, doesn't Visual Studio have a "use eclipse shortcut" feature like IntelliJ has?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Because of the lack of information out there on this, let's start a community wiki answer.  Please add additional information on migration tips to this answer.  Please avoid 3rd party plug-ins such as ReSharper in the answer.

### Shortcut Keys

```
+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|   Command            |   Eclipse shortcut  |   VS.NET shortcut   |
+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|   Delete line        |    Ctrl-D           |    Ctrl-L           |
|   Comment line       |    Ctrl-/           |    Ctrl-K-C         |
|   Uncomment line     |    Ctrl-/           |    Ctrl-K-U         |
|   Toggle editor tabs |    Ctrl-F6          |    Ctrl-F6          |
|   Goto Line          |    Ctrl-L           |    Ctrl-G           |
|   Goto Definition    |    Ctrl-Click or F3 |    F12              |
|   Find next          |    Ctrl-K           |    F3               |
|   Find previous      |    Ctrl-Shift-K     |    Shift-F3         |
|   Go backward        |    Alt-LeftArrow    |    Ctrl-minus       |
|   Go forward         |    Alt-RightArrow   |    Ctrl-Shift-minus |
|   Find usage         |    Ctrl-Shift-G     |    Ctrl-K-R         |
|   Rename             |    Alt-Shift-R      |    Ctrl-R-R         |
|   Refactor           |    Alt-Shift-T      |    none             |
|   Open Type          |    Ctrl-Shift-T     |    Ctrl-,           |
|   Navigate To        |    Ctrl-Shift-R     |    Ctrl-,           |
+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Delete line - the standard "Cut" Ctrl-X in VS cuts the whole line, if there's nothing selected. I use it all the time.

Comment: But it eats the clipboard.  There's a plugin that doesn't do that.

Comment: Note that the equivalent of eclipse ctrl-k is not F3 is is ctrl-F3. (F3 does not find next selected it finds next for previously searched  string in find operation)

Answer (score 9):

This will sound flippant, but assuming you're going to be using C#, the most important point is: buy [ReSharper](http://jetbrains.com/resharper). At that point you'll have a lot of what you're used to - integrated unit tests, find resource, find type (with Camel-casing etc), better Intellisense and more.

After that, learn that the most important keyboard shortcuts are Ctrl-. for "give me the list of things you can do for me automatically" and Alt-Enter which is the same but for ReSharper suggestions.

There are various ReSharper and VS shortcut key cheat sheets on the web - I suspect you can find those as quickly as I can :)

Answer (score 3):

I've been slowly customizing my Visual Studio 2008 to create a few tricks like when I used Eclipse. I recommend these two as a starting point:

1. Rock Scroll - Text Highlight with an enhanced scroll bar. Very neat tool to help you visually locate where a variable is used along the code: 
   http://microsoftdev.blogspot.com/2008/05/rock-scroll-visual-studio-plugin.html
2. Quick Open File - create a shortcut that you like and voila, you can quickly access any file in your project: http://kutny.net/vsopen/

I've blogged about this here: http://www.wagnerdanda.me/2010/08/visual-studio-tips-like-eclipse/