# Eclipse keyboard bindings in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving From Eclipse to Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777562/moving-from-eclipse-to-visual-studio-2008)

Is there anyway to mimic the majority of Eclipse keyboard bindings in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the VS keyboard-shortcuts in the options.

If done once, you can export them using the "Import / Export Settings" Wizard.